# Sometimes When I launched the Application into the device by using Xcode, I got a dyld`gdb_image_notifier exception

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod

I have designed the application by using Xcode 5.0 version. but sometimes when i launched the app with new version of Xcode 5.1 was giving dyld`gdb_image_notifier exception.


`In Debug Area`

dyld`gdb_image_notifier:
0x2befc0cc:  bx     lr

In Thread List

In Thread 1,
0 gdb_image_notifier

## 6 0x2befc22e in dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)

Comment: Due to missing resources in Framework bundle, keep it optional.